# Driver with the longest time between F1 race starts

Tags: trivia, formula-1

Robert Kubica, who last drove for Renault in the 2010 season, is now confirmed to be back on the grid for Williams next year, over 8 years since his last Grand Prix start.

Assuming he goes on to start the race at next year's Australian GP, will it then become the longest time in between two race starts for any driver?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not quite. Jan Lammers started the [1982 Dutch Grand Prix](https://www.formula1.com/en/results.html/1982/races/445/netherlands.html) on July 3rd 1982, and left the sport at the end of that season. He then returned for the end of the 1992 season and started two further races, the first of which was the [1992 Japanese Grand Prix](https://www.formula1.com/en/results.html/1992/races/588/japan.html) on October 25th 1992, a gap of 10 years, 3 months and 22 days.

Kubica, by comparison, will return after a gap of 8 years, 4 months and 3 days assuming he starts the 2019 Australian Grand Prix on March 17th.